# Google Maps API: Visualize the Growth of my Users over Time with respect to their Location

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, data-visualization

I recently came across [www.morethanamap.com](http://www.morethanamap.com) showcasing the various ways you can use Google's Map API within one of your apps.  I'm particularly interested in the [population visualization](http://www.morethanamap.com/demos/visualization/population).  I have a website that's been around for a few years and I'd like to map the growth of my user base onto a map of the United States.

The above website and their demonstrations were really interesting but I didn't find any documentation on how to actually build/replicate any of the examples.

So, my question is: **How would I go about visualize the growth of my users over time with respect to their location?**  I have the following data:

1. Date user's account was created
2. Zipcode of user (also city & state)

I'm really just looking for someone to point me in the right direction.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to decide what area criteria to use. Zipcodes will have the greatest and state the smallest ammount of markers on the map.

If your data is stored in MySQL or similar database you can query it on different time periods to obtain count of users.

Using [MarkerClusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html) will probably the best method of display

Comment: I'm more interested in using the heat map effect, as opposed to the markers.  With that in mind, do you think I should use cities as opposed to zipcodes?

Comment: As I said it depend on your data and the area covered.